# How to print sideways in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, design-patterns, while-loop, nested-loops

I want to print a triangl. I am getting my expected result but it's printing in consecutive lines. I want to print the "*" sideways for every for loop's output. How do I do it?

Code:

```
let a,b,c;
a = 5;
b = 1;
while(b <= a){
  for(c=1;c<=b;c++){
    console.log('*');
  }
  b++;
  console.log('\n')
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: a) Don't use `console.log` but a `print` function b) accumulate the characters into a string and only log it when you want to output a complete line

Comment: Create the string first and *then* print it. The console always prints a new line, there isn't anything like `System.out.print` as in Java.

Comment: What you want to achieve? You are printing everything on console, every output it will print on new line

Comment: I am a bit new in JavaScript.....The tutorial I am following is printing using console.log() hence I am using it too. I really don't know much about print function. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the sample

```js
let a,b,c;
let stars ="";
a = 5;
b = 1;
while(b <= a){
  for(c=1;c<=b;c++){
    stars += '*';
  }
  b++;
  stars += '\n';
}
console.log(stars)
```

Comment: Thanks @Bharat broher for ur efforts.
I finally solved it myself also, Thanks a lot though....really appreciated ur efforts! :D

Comment: Glad you were able to solve by yourself.  I saw @Bergi and VLAZ had already put the comment on it. My bad

Comment: No problem. Actually, they gave me the idea of making it a string by concatenating..... after googling for a while, I was able to pick up the syntax and applied it to my code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the answer myself. By concatenating as a string.
Here is the solve.

```
let a,b,c,x;
a = 5;
b = 1;
while(b <= a){
  x = ' ';
  for(c=1;c<=b;c++){
      x = "* "+x;
    }
  console.log(x);
  b++;
  console.log('\n')
}
```